# Put focus on XUL textbox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm doing a Firefox extension. The extension has a sidebar. In this sidebar, I created some textboxes dynamically. How I can put the focus on the last textbox that I created?

This is the code, I want to put the focus in the textbox **"userResponse"** . The textbox is a XUL element.

```
var textResponse= document.createElement("textbox");
textResponse.setAttribute("id", "userResponse");
textResponse.setAttribute("class", "question");
textResponse.setAttribute("title", "Type your question here");
textResponse.onkeypress = numberOfResults;
textResponse.focus("");
var trResponse = document.createElement("tr");
var tdResponse = document.createElement("td");
tdResponse.appendChild(textResponse);
trResponse.appendChild(tdResponse);
tableQuestion.appendChild(trResponse);
```

I tried it with `document.getElementById("userResponse").focus()` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`textResponse.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Method/focus) is the correct way - but without parameters and **after** adding this element to the document. You can retrieve that element again of course by using `document.getElementById()` - but same thing there, you should do it **after** the element has been added to the document.

Comment: Yes Wladimir, I do the focus after adding the element to the document, but nothing happens.